# C# - Exibir resultados de busca em DataGridView (SELECT SQL)

Tags: c#, sql, query, select, datagridview

Olá!
Eu estou começando efetivamente no C# e já tenho pequenos projetos.
Já consigo conectar ao banco de dados remoto, já consigo executar queries, só não consigo pegar o resultado de um Select e mostrar em um DataGridView.
Sinceramente, se houver um método/elemento mais simples de trabalhar que o DataGridView, ficarei feliz.

Uso esse código para criar a conexão/comando

```
static SqlConnection conect = new SqlConnection("Data Source=meuip;Initial Catalog=db;User ID=sa;Password=senha");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Tabela where login='usuario'",conect);
        SqlDataReader dr;
```

e depois, num botão específico, vem o problema.
Não sei como prosseguir.

```
        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        conect.Open();
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.HasRows)
        {
            if (dr.Read())
            {
               // Quero colocar os Resultados daqui num DataGridView. E agora?
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Esta usando winforms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o SqlDataAdapter e DataSet.

```
string sql_query = "SELECT * FROM Tabela where login='usuario'";

SqlDataAdapter data = new SqlDataAdapter(sql_query, conect);
DataSet tabela = new DataSet();
SqlCommandBuilder cmd = new SqlCommandBuilder(data);
data.Fill(tabela);
dataGridView1.DataSource = tabela.tables[0];
```